# Is it possible to change all date fields containing the same date at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible, when a user changes the date in one of the inputs to change the date in all the other inputs with matching 'initial' attribute? This is what I have for now. It's far from the solution I'm looking for, but can't figure out where to go from there...

```js
$('.date-input').change(function () {
    //var initial = $(".date-input").attr('data-stake');
      $(".date-input").val($(this).val())   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" class="date-input" value="2021-06-21" initial="2021-06-21" />
<input type="date" class="date-input" value="2021-06-22" initial="2021-06-21" />
<input type="date" class="date-input" value="2021-06-22" initial="2021-06-22" />
<input type="date" class="date-input" value="2021-06-23" initial="2021-06-22" />
```

Comment: can you give a more concrete example of what you want the result to be - is it something like, if you change the the 22/6/2021 date to 22/7/2021, then the dates would be 21/7/2021, 22/7/2021, 23/7/2021 and 24/7/2021 ... i.e. since they started a day apart they should end a day apart?

Comment: Pleae note that your HTML is invalid. There is no `initial` attribute on `HTMLInputElement`. Use `data-initial` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

NOTE: data-attributes are recommended over custom attributes

Shorter version

```js
$(".date-input").on("change", function() {
  const initial = this.dataset.initial;
  $(`[data-initial="${initial}"`).each((i,ele) => ele.value=this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" class="date-input" value="2021-06-21" data-initial="2021-06-21" />
<input type="date" class="date-input" value="2021-06-22" data-initial="2021-06-21" />
<input type="date" class="date-input" value="2021-06-22" data-initial="2021-06-22" />
<input type="date" class="date-input" value="2021-06-23" data-initial="2021-06-22" />
```

Using filter instead

```js
const $dates = $(".date-input");
$dates.on("change", function() {
  const initial = this.dataset.initial;
  const date = this.value;
  $dates.filter(function() {
   return  this.dataset.initial === initial
  }).each(function() { 
    this.value = date
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" class="date-input" value="2021-06-21" data-initial="2021-06-21" />
<input type="date" class="date-input" value="2021-06-22" data-initial="2021-06-21" />
<input type="date" class="date-input" value="2021-06-22" data-initial="2021-06-22" />
<input type="date" class="date-input" value="2021-06-23" data-initial="2021-06-22" />
```

Comment: Why not using the `attr` selector?

Comment: @Nitheesh Because I wanted to filter. See updated example for a shorter version

Answer (score 0):

Try usibg jQuer [attr](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector

```js
$('.date-input').change(function () {
  console.log($(this))
  $(`.date-input[initial=${$(this).attr('initial')}]`).val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" class="date-input" value="2021-06-21" initial="2021-06-21" />
<input type="date" class="date-input" value="2021-06-22" initial="2021-06-21" />
<input type="date" class="date-input" value="2021-06-22" initial="2021-06-22" />
<input type="date" class="date-input" value="2021-06-23" initial="2021-06-22" />
```